windows 10 network cable unplugged event removes TCP connection
kind people.
My computer has multiple network interfaces( Intel I210) and runs Windows 10.   I use TCPView to monitor the TCP connections established between Putty SSH client  and Linux during the cable unplugging phase.
When I enable only one of the  network interface and keep the other interfaces disabled, each time I unplug the cable all ESTABLISHED tcp connection won't be affected.  If I replug the network cable some seconds later, all TCP connection are well kept.
TCP connection well kept
But when I enable two or more network interface(all cables connected),  ESTABLISHED tcp connections disappear very soon after I unplug the network cable.
I also did the same test under windows 7 and Linux. No matter how many interfaces are being used, Unplugging the network cable won't affect ESTABLISHED connections.
TCP connection removed or not when unplugging cable depends upon how many network interfaces are in use. This behavior on Windows 10 is strange and I want to know whether this behavior is configurable or it is designed by purpose.
I developped an client-server pair running on on Windows 7 and Linux which use TCP to communicate .  Attributed to TCP, transient network link state change are handled properly. Unfortunately, when I try porting them to Windows 10, transient network link state change cause the client to malfunction. I know by adding OSI Session Layer over TCP protocol could solve this. But the session state bookkeeping and recovery drives me crazy.
